# Do we need "support"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

As of now [support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/support) has 137 questions tagged. There is no proper information about its usage on the site. The existing information looks vague. So, should we re-tag all questions and remove [support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/support) from the site or try to improve its usage information?

Comment: Maybe it should be renamed/clarified as `commercial-support` or `canonical-support`? But we'd still have to re-tag probably 90% of what it has now.

Comment: @ByteCommander I don't think "commercial support" is on-topic here. Also, if we mention `canonical-support`, what would be the definition?

Comment: To be fair, Ask Ubuntu isn't tech support site - we're Q&A type of site, where we just happen to troubleshoot certain issues in order to answer questions, so this tag probably shouldn't be used to request help and troubleshooting - we already do some of that. We could use this tag for questions regarding Canonical's intentions behind supporting releases, what does the support of those releases include, etc. For example, the recent announcement about 18.04 having 10 year support would fit greatly into that category.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy true, but we'd still need to rename the tag to something more descriptive. `support` alone tells you very little.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I do agree but consider [this question by muru](https://askubuntu.com/q/1093582/816190). This question asked for information about 10 year support yet support tag wasn't used. So, IMO this tag might not be required at all.

Comment: @Kulfy The fact that the tag wasn't used doesn't mean much.  There's plenty of questions asking about shell scripting yet not tagged [scripts]. That's what we can do - re-tag questions when necessary, add or remove the relevant ones.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy The fact that a tag exist doesn't mean much either. Stick with tags that are effectively and activelly used by answerers.

Comment: @Braiam Isnt the whole point of this question "This tag exists, we gotta do something about it?" Lol.  I am more focused om tag relevance. What is used is not always relevant, as the numerous posts on meta show

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy tags follow the "I think, therefore I am" thinking. Tags needs to fulfill a purpose before creation. People tend to create tags as if they were hashtags instead.

Comment: @Braiam If there is no relevance and no wili the purpose is unclear.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy exactly. Unclear tags aren't useful to neither the askers nor the answerers.

Comment: @Kulfy  I'm not suggesting whether or not the tag is required on a question. I'm suggesting re-purposing the tag. Instead of deleting it completely - give it particular wiki and clearly-defined usage.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I do agree, but again question arises what would be the definition (usage guidance) of tag then?

Comment: @Kulfy I've already proposed one definition with my very first comment. I'm out of this discussion for now.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, I can't find that announcement about the 10 year support; could you please give a link?

Comment: @Wildcard See the question by Muru that Kulfy linked earlier, for reference that's https://askubuntu.com/q/1093582/295286  Also see the official Ubuntu blog (muru linked that as well): https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/11/15/openstack-summit-berlin-mark-shuttleworth

Answer (score 3):

While I would not go so far as to say that the posts in [support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/support) have nothing in common with each other at all, I do not think grouping them with this tag is useful.

The questions fall into three categories:

- Questions about support periods for Ubuntu versions.
- Questions about hardware or software working or not on Ubuntu.
- People who want our support or someone else's are tagging their questions with [support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/support).

Of these, the second and third categories are IMHO much too broad to be grouped by a tag. The first category, support periods for Ubuntu versions, could possibly benefit from being grouped by a tag, but it should have a less ambiguous name, such as [support-period](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/support-period).

Comment: Not just Ubuntu's support period but they are also about [Java support period](https://askubuntu.com/q/1167617/), [Python 2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1127122/), [device compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/q/1159818/) and [some are really about Ubuntu support](https://askubuntu.com/q/649503/)

Comment: @Kulfy device compatibility and the Python question are the second category. The support period of Java versions *as such* is off-topic, but the question about it you linked to is the second category too IMHO. Questions about paid support (I only saw a couple) could be tagged [paid-support]?

Comment: Aren't *Questions about hardware or software working or not on Ubuntu.* and *What would happen to python 2* different?